# PySpark Pandas UDF applied with Series changes Data Type from Float to Int

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

This is what I am trying to do:

[image]

I am still learning PySpark and right now I am exploring Pandas UDFs. The picture embedded above is self-explanatory. I have the column `long` with values such as -122.23. Then I define a UDF where I simply want to turn that into a positive number. But, even though I tried also forcing the `pd.Series` to be cast as `float`, or multiplying the series with `-1.0`, the results I get are rounded to the nearest integer.

The same thing happens when I create a UDF which adds or subtracts. I am losing the floating point precision here and didn't really find anything on the web or knew how to search for an answer for this issue.

Comment: Hello @aleen, welcome to SO! I hope you will enjoy learning here as much as I do! :D One thing, don't post images of your code, insert it as a text. Please see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `long` in `pandas_udf`, to represent floating numbers you can use `DoubleType` (or `FloatType`, depending on the precision).

UDF example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType


@F.pandas_udf(DoubleType())
def neg_to_pos(x):
    return abs(x)


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
data = [(-1.2331,), (1.0,), (234.23,), (-0.233,)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["a"])
df = df.select(neg_to_pos(df.a))
```

Where input DF is:

```
+-------+                                                                       
|a      |
+-------+
|-1.2331|
|1.0    |
|234.23 |
|-0.233 |
+-------+
```

and result is:

```
+-------------+
|neg_to_pos(a)|
+-------------+
|1.2331       |
|1.0          |
|234.23       |
|0.233        |
+-------------+
```

However, the same can be done without UDF, using just one line:

```
df = df.select(F.abs("a"))
```

Comment: Oh, that was very helpful. This is not well explained in the [Quickstart Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/quickstart_df.html).